# Sum of multiple column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
Linetotal tax taxsum
--------------------
1150      Bed  250
1150      HSC  150
1150      CESS 110
```

I want the sum of total of `taxsum` (250 + 150 + 110) and `linetotal` (1150) = 1660.

Can this be done in SQL Server using a T-SQL query?

Comment: yes.............................

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Can you please add the output you're trying to get for this sample data?

Comment: what exactly i need is (1150+250+150+110).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select sum(taxsum) + avg(linetotal)
From yourtable
```

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, go ahead and upvote it and mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax you wanna use

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Your code can be used as (**Assuming your table name is GetTheSum**)

```
SELECT SUM(taxsum) AS TAXTOTAL FROM GetTheSum;
```

FINAL ANSWER:

```
SELECT (Linetotal + taxsum) AS TOTAL FROM GetTheSum
```

Comment: The last query does not return the value asked by OP. It would return: (1150+1150+1150)+(250+150+110)=3.960

Comment: I've edited the answer, check it out now. It should return (1150+250+150+110).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT SUM(taxsum) AS Taxes, SUM(LineTotal) + SUM(taxsum) AS Total
FROM mytable
GROUP BY LineTotal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this wit a sub query.

```
SELECT Linetotal + s FROM (
    SELECT Linetotal, sum(taxsum) s FROM table_name GROUP BY Linetotal
) a
```

Or Just

```
SELECT Linetotal + sum(taxsum) AS total FROM table_name GROUP BY Linetotal
```

Note: the question is bit unclear. I am assuming you want to sum `taxsum` for each `Linetotal` and add `Linetotal` once to it.